# `hostapd` running but unable to join network

Tags: networking, pi-4, hostapd

I'm building out a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.5 with 8 GB running on Raspbian 11, into an all-in-one roller derby scoreboard and I've hit a snag with the WiFi access point component.

The SSID isn't visible and devices cannot join the network.

`systemctl` says it's running but I'm unable to join a device to the network.

Here is my `hostapd.conf` file

```
ssid=scoreboard
wpa_passphrase=xxx12345

interface=wlan0
hw_mode=g
channel=7
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

Here is the output from `sudo systemctl status hostapd.service`

```
● hostapd.service - Access point and authentication server for Wi-Fi and Ethernet
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/hostapd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2022-12-10 12:56:16 PST; 2min 7s ago
       Docs: man:hostapd(8)
    Process: 674 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/hostapd -B -P /run/hostapd.pid -B $DAEMON_OPTS ${DAEMON_CONF} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 701 (hostapd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
        CPU: 103ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/hostapd.service
             └─701 /usr/sbin/hostapd -B -P /run/hostapd.pid -B /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf

Dec 10 12:56:15 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Access point and authentication server for Wi-Fi and Ethernet...
Dec 10 12:56:15 raspberrypi hostapd[674]: Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
Dec 10 12:56:15 raspberrypi hostapd[674]: Using interface wlan0 with hwaddr e4:5f:01:cd:94:b4 and ssid "scoreboard"
Dec 10 12:56:16 raspberrypi hostapd[674]: wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->ENABLED
Dec 10 12:56:16 raspberrypi hostapd[674]: wlan0: AP-ENABLED
Dec 10 12:56:16 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Access point and authentication server for Wi-Fi and Ethernet.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update 1:**

I changed the channel number and now the network is visible. I try to join the network, enter the passkey, and hit join. Nothing happens. I hit join again and get a notice that I couldn't join the network.

(Removed the log lines as they took up too much space.)

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Gfay8NlPDvW5W-_n_siVsLI759YANlBh0UMlm-IbVII/edit?usp=sharing

**Update 2**

Here's the current `ifconfig`

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.132  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        inet6 2603:3023:197:4860:a1a:19c5:714b:1bac  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::7164:a264:2149:ce46  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fdf3:22a0:ac61:1:2c42:a7b:3b01:5d2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether e4:5f:01:cd:94:b3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 66976  bytes 35499840 (33.8 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 29231  bytes 4287387 (4.0 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1415  bytes 1226336 (1.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1415  bytes 1226336 (1.1 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.4.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.4.255
        inet6 fe80::a9e0:63d2:14c2:c8e4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fdf3:22a0:ac61:1:511f:637c:cae4:129f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2603:3023:197:4860:51be:9bf2:dca1:acad  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether e4:5f:01:cd:94:b4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 14294  bytes 3779517 (3.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1164  bytes 191829 (187.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The current `dhcpdc.conf` (comments removed)

```
rollerderby
clientid
persistent
option rapid_commit
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
option interface_mtu
require dhcp_server_identifier
slaac private
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.4.1/24
static routers=192.168.4.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.4.1
denyinterfaces eth0
denyinterfaces wlan0
```

The `dnsmasq.conf`

```
interface=wlan0
dhcp-range=192.168.4.11,192.168.4.254,255.255.255.0,24h
```

Error lines from `sudo hostapd -d -t /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`

```
1671074665.251692: nl80211: flush -> DEL_STATION wlan0 (all)
1671074665.251734: nl80211: Station flush failed: ret=-14 (Bad address)
1671074665.251788: wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=0 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
1671074665.251833: nl80211: set_key failed; err=-22 Invalid argument)
1671074665.251847: Failed to clear default encryption keys (ifname=wlan0 keyidx=0)
1671074665.251881: wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=1 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
1671074665.251922: nl80211: set_key failed; err=-22 Invalid argument)
1671074665.251936: Failed to clear default encryption keys (ifname=wlan0 keyidx=1)
1671074665.251968: wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=2 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
1671074665.252006: nl80211: set_key failed; err=-22 Invalid argument)
1671074665.252018: Failed to clear default encryption keys (ifname=wlan0 keyidx=2)
1671074665.252052: wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=3 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
1671074665.252089: nl80211: set_key failed; err=-22 Invalid argument)
1671074665.252104: Failed to clear default encryption keys (ifname=wlan0 keyidx=3)
```

Comment: Suggestions: try a different channel eg 6 or try: `hw_mode=a`. Then restart the service and see if the AP becomes visible.

Comment: @Kate With channel 6, the SSID is visible but I can't join. That's closer.

Comment: Good. Now try this: stop the service (`systemctl stop hostapd`), then run this as root in a console: `hostapd -d /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf` (double-check the path to the conf file, I'm not 100% sure). This will start hostapd in the foreground and display messages to the console. Try to connect to the AP and look at the log carefully. Perhaps the problem will become clear. You can edit your question to add the output of this command for analysis.

Comment: @Kate Well, that was interesting. See update 1.

Comment: Gut feeling, but is your system including firmware up to date? And to be clear, we are talking about the onboard wifi right, not a USB dongle (which may require a different driver)? Other than nl80211 rtl_*xxxx* is also common depending on the **chipset**.

Comment: @Kate I've verified that both Raspbian and the firmware are up to date. Yes, it's the onboard WiFi.

Comment: @Kate I got it working. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working! The WiFi network is visible and it can be joined!

This article was super helpful in that process. https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point/install-software

Here are the final configuration files that I updated.

**`/etc/dhcpcd.conf` (comment lines removed)**

```
rollerderby
clientid
persistent
set
option rapid_commit
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
option interface_mtu

require dhcp_server_identifier

slaac private

interface wlan0
    static ip_address=192.168.4.1/24
    nohook wpa_supplicant

denyinterfaces eth0
denyinterfaces wlan0
```

**`/etc/sysctl.d/routed-ap.conf`**

```
# Enable IPv4 routing
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

**`/etc/dnsmasq.conf`**

```
interface=wlan0
dhcp-range=192.168.4.10,192.168.4.25,255.255.255.0,24h
domain=derbywifi
address=/toaster.derbywifi/192.168.4.1
```

**`/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`**

```
country_code=US
interface=wlan0
ssid=notTheSSID
hw_mode=a
channel=48
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=notThePassword
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

**`Run These Commands`**

```
sudo apt install netfilter-persistent
sudo raspi-config nonint do_wifi_country US
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo netfilter-persistent save
sudo reboot
```